# Nuxt Async Data - Server is Caching

Tags: vue.js, caching, nuxt.js

Im using `nuxt` with `asyncData()` to make an axios request to an endpoint. In my build i'm using pre-rendered HTML pages.

I have a set of products on the API end-point and we've just remove most of the products, however they are still showing the full product list.

So I started up my dev server and hit the endpoint and I am seeing the correct updated API list from the endpoint.

So it seems my server is caching the API call. I'm not using a node server, just uploading my pre-rendered html to a server.

It's just I'm trying to isolate the problem and wanted to know if it is a configuration with `nuxt.js` that will allow me to not cache from the endpoint or is this a strictly a server issue that is causing the API data to be cached?

Or is there a config that I can use in the AXIOS request to always give me a fresh copy?

Answer (score 0):

are you running nuxt with static site generation? in this case nuxt fetches all products from your API at the time it generates the static html. so the nuxt-server does not know anything about the updated api-data.

you could solve this by using a hook and re-building the page every time the api-data changes.

edit: you can find more info in the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/concepts/static-site-generation)

Comment: Yes, i'm using static site generation. The docs are only general. What would be the hook? Building into the API call or setting the page not to cache. Is the cache client side or server side?

Comment: you could do both. if you have a cms hosted on netlify for example you could do the following: if you update a page in the cms -> call build hook on netlify. nuxt rebuilds and calls the apis from the cms. 

if your api-data changes more frequently it's better to do the fetching only on the client (and not on der server at build time). you could use fetch() and set `fetchOnServer` to false -> https://nuxtjs.org/guides/features/data-fetching/